# swift 2.3 onesignal ios 10 not working

Tags: ios10, onesignal, swift2

i have a problem with onesignal, my app use swift 2.3 and it run ok on ios 9.3, but on ios 10.x it not working: i don't reseive any notification.
Anyone help this please.

Comment: Same problem here. I got error when trying to install pod. OneSignal required by twets (Swift 2.3), OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension (Swift 3.0).